How can you distinguish a build from a repository class programatiically looking at tasks in Jenkins.instance.queue.items
We are having issues with repo scans burning through our api limit and I want to modify jobdsl seed job such that after it runs, it stops storm of repo-scans.  We use webhooks any way so the scans aren't really necessary (except to force execution of log rotation).
Jenkins.instance.queue.items Is the queue but I'm not sure how to tell a build from a repo scan.
It looks like the following are there.  I just haven't yet been able to identify a scan

org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.ExecutorStepExecution$PlaceholderTask


Is Jenkins.instance.queue.items the queue for this kind of tasks? I don't know, I always thought it's strictly for jobs.

oh well that'd explain it.  They do show up in the UI of the queue so I assumed that'd be in the queue.items.   However, sounds like I need to look at the UI code to figure out what it's doing and work my way back down.
